# Displaying a modal just below a Button -React native

Tags: react-native

We can keep a component in native android as in layout_below of some component id. How can we do that in react native? Lets say I have a modal or an alert box and I want it to display just below a particular Button when it is clicked. How can I do that?

Please have a look at the video https://youtu.be/gIjIZlgpTyI . Here you'll see the modal appears in the center all the time. What I want is that If I scroll the screen, the button (with text 12 Noon to 3PM) moves up and the modal box should appear just below it when the button is clicked.

In the following code, I am using marginTop to the modal components style which doesn't work ideally.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        modalVisible: false,
    };
}

setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
}
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',}}
                              onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}>
                <Text style={[styles.timeTable, styles.orange]}>12 Noon to 3PM, 7PM to 1AM </Text>
                <Icon style={[styles.timeTable, styles.orange]} name='ios-arrow-down'/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modal
                animationType="fade"
                transparent={true}
                visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                    alert('Modal has been closed.');
                }}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
                                          onPress={() => this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)}>

                    <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.4)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        bottom: 0
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            flexDirection: 'column',
                            backgroundColor: '#fff',
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            borderRadius: 2,
                            shadowRadius: 10,
                            marginTop: '77%',
                            // height: 200,
                            marginRight: 28,
                            marginLeft: 28
                        }}>
                            <View style={{flex: 1,marginTop: 25, marginLeft: 25,}}>
                                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',}}>Opening Hours</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    )
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have any image or gif for the same ?

Comment: thanks...  see the video https://youtu.be/gIjIZlgpTyI . Here you'll see the modal appears in the center all the time. What I want is that If I scroll the screen, the button (with text 12 Noon to 3PM) moves up and the modal box should appear just below it when the button is clicked.

Comment: I have gone through the video and your question again, as u said you can keep a component in native android as in layout_below of some component id in the same manner instead of displaying a modal you can use a view below your button(with text 12 Noon to 3PM) which will display the data inside it. This view will toggle whenever you click the button(with text 12 Noon to 3PM). Let me know if u are looking for something else.

Comment: But that view should appear on top of the screen. It should not appear underneath the button within the same screen.